# duplicate the Bootstrap flexbox grid system with media breakpoints

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to duplicate the `flexbox` grid system from Bootstrap. Everything works great except the media query part.
The columns stack nicely horizontally, but when a specific media breakpoint gets activated I want to stack the div's on a new line.

I guess I can do it with jQuery, but I want to try to achieve it with pure `css` first. I tried to look at the source files for Bootstrap but couldn't make much sense of it.

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: auto; 
}

.row > .col {
  padding: 14px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
}

.col-md-4 {
  padding: 14px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 33.33333%; 
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-4 {
      //code wanted
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:burlywood;">MyColumn 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:chartreuse;">MyColumn 2</div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:crimson;">MyColumn 3</div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:crimson;">MyColumn 4</div>
</div>
```

the inline styling is only for testing purposes.

Comment: Why not just use the [Bootstrap 4 grid only CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files)?

Comment: because I'm trying to make my own framework which is more directed at my custom controls (Tag Helpers). the only thing left is the flexbox grid

Answer (score 2):

You had the media query declaration inside of another `css` rule.

A simple solution is to change the stacking direction of the `.row` itself.

**Edit:**

If you're just trying to learn, this is fine. However, if you want to use this in production I would recommend that you copy just the grid definitions out of bootstrap instead of reinventing the wheel.

That aside, know that bootstrap is mobile first. Your original example is not. What I added below is `flex-wrap` and wildcarded `*` the `box-sizing` property. That's most of the magic.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;} /* borders will break your layout without this */
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*this is how columns 'wrap' on smaller devices */
}

.row>.col {
  padding: 14px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.col-md-4 {
  padding: 14px 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {/*bootstrap uses media queries for larger screens, not smaller */
  .col-md-4 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:burlywood;">MyColumn 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:chartreuse;">MyColumn 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:crimson;">MyColumn 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm yes. but wont all the children stack horizontally? or can I set direction on a single element?

Comment: Amended my answer.

Comment: thanks it's a step in the right direction. I guess I have to try some things out. I'm thinking about removing elements from the flex container on media breakpoint using jQuery, and insert them beneath the row. not sexy but I guess it will do the job

Comment: I would strongly advice against that, but I don't really know what your goal here is.

Comment: for example I want all col's with MD breakpoint to stack vertically beneath the elements in the flexbox on all lower breakpoints. Wrap kinda works, but not perfectely. I want to keep flex-wrap: nowrap so the remaining col's stays in line. Badly explained, but yeah